# Could awaiting network cause client timeouts?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await

I have a server that is doing work instructed by an Azure queue. It is almost always on very high CPU doing multiple tasks in parallel and some of the tasks use `Parallel.ForEach`.
During the running of the tasks I write analytic events to another Azure queue by calling `CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync` with await.

I noticed thousands of these analytic writings that fail with the following error:

`WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`

I checked Azure's storage event logs, and I have a nice bunch of `PutMessage` commands that take 80.000ms end to end, but they only take 1ms for Azure itself. The HTTP status code I get is 500 and Azure describes the reason as client timeout.

What I think is happening is that my code calls the `AddMessageAsync` and from that point my thread is released and the network driver is sending the request and waiting for a response. When getting a response, the network driver needs a thread to get the response and a task is scheduled to do that and calls my continuation. Because my server is constantly on high load, the task takes a long time to get a thread and by then the Azure server decides this is a client timeout.

The code calling azure:

```
await cloudQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(aMessageContent));
```

The exception:

```
StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result):11
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__3(IAsyncResult ar):45
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task):82
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task):41
AzureCommon.Data.AsyncQueueDataContext+<AddMessage>d__d.MoveNext() in c:\BuildAgent\work\14078ab89161833\Azure\AzureCommon\Data\Async\AsyncQueueDataContext.cs:60
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task):82
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task):41
AzureCommon.Storage.AzureEvent+<DispatchAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\BuildAgent\work\14078ab89161833\Azure\AzureCommon\Events\AzureEvent.cs:354

WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult):41
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult):44
```

Am I right about why this is happening? If so, would using a single-threaded synchronization context for this call be better for me?

A row from Azure storage log. You can find details about what each property means [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343259.aspx).

```
<request-start-time>            <operation-type>     <request-status>     <http-status-code>    <end-to-end-latency-in-ms>      <server-latency-in-ms>
2014-07-29T14:55:20.0794198Z    PutMessage           ClientTimeoutError   500                   86929                           1
```

Thanks.

Comment: well maybe ... why don't you go and try it?

Comment: @CarstenKönig I probably will, but I lack a lot of knowledge on how these network driver-thread relationship works. So I'd like to know if what I think the problem might be is a possible scenario, or maybe it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Your theory regarding the network driver is very likely not true. Post the code where you are getting this error. Post the full exception. "500 server error" means *the server crashed* not the client.

Comment: @usr I added the code and the exception. I know that 500 means the server crashed, but Azure storage logs say the returned code is 500 and the reason is a client timeout. Because of this I assume that if my client doesn't intercept the response quickly enough, Azure return this error (Although this code does not seem a good fit).

Comment: Azure cannot find out whether your client quickly accepted the response or not. It cannot tell and therefore cannot generate that error. What exactly are the Azure logs saying? Post all detail that you can get hold of. Also, post the RequestResult stored in that StorageException. The first step when debugging is to look at *all* error information.

Comment: @usr Correct me if I'm wrong, in TCP the server does know whether I am getting all the data from him, because after sending the first packet he is waiting for a response from me to continue with the rest of the packets. I added a row from the log, hope this helps.

Comment: @mot the server does not generally receive a confirmation immediately. In any case this information is generally not available to user-mode programs. That said there might be something to your theory: Maybe there is not enough CPU time available to complete the .NET processing of AddMessageAsync. Anyway, I'm out of ideas. Try running the CPU intensive work on a low-priority TaskScheduler.

Comment: @mot In which environment are you running this app? IIS? Windows Service?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Azure cloud worker

Comment: I know you're calling azure worker, but where from?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The role is executed by Azure through it's Main method and loops through a queue forever. No IIS or requests from other things.

Comment: Could you post the code which queries? I assume its inside your `Run` method.

Comment: Usually when you have high-CPU consumption, it's common to a host refuse TCP connections. Your scenario fits this problems. Check if you have CPU spikes while trying to do that. I think there's no relation with async/await. Probably the only relation is that async/await will make the clients waits less time to send new requests, increasing the load on the server and improving performance.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I might be able to post the loop code (or did you mean something else by queries?) when I'll be at the office.

Comment: @EricLemes Do you know what can be done to prevent this? I am aiming towards having a service that does very little CPU consuming work, and mainly does network calls.

Comment: Your problem fits my assumption? Usually there's no way to avoid this, just controlling the load. Probably if you use some kind of load balancing (hardware or software) you won't have this problem. Other way to workaround this is creating a logic to retry failed packages. We can't assume that a remote host will be allways available.

Answer (score 0):

The error 500 means that the server has received a bad request or it has crashed for various other reasons. I don't believe that it has to do with the high load of your threads. Please consider taking the following actions:

- Check the name of the queue you are using. The name needs to be lowercase, starting with a character. This is a common issue that causes error 500 with no enlighting error message from the server.
- Set up the retry policy of the Azure Storage SDK client, preferably with an Exponential retry policy.
- Make sure you are using the latest Azure Storage SDK, as the underlying protocol has recently changed to a more efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

['Bad Request' is a 400 error, not a 500 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).  A 500 Error indicates any kind of server error, so it's perfectly reasonable to get that response, and many client-side libraries will use a 500 error code for similar types of unexpected issues.

Normally a 'client timeout' response would never make it to the client (because it timed out!). The only situation I can think of where a client timeout response could make it to the client would be if the request was more than a single network packet and the client was too slow in sending packets after the first one. This could easily be caused by CPU contention on the client device. I would recommend using a higher priority thread for listening to network responses but then immediately pass off the processing of the response to a normal priority thread. Overloaded CPU will cause all sorts of timeout issues because the code can't tell the difference between a network response not coming in soon enough and the CPU not scheduling the listener in time to receive the response (or even to send the request). Even local disk I/O and locking can timeout in these situations, depending on the underlying implementation.